# Read-only association with JPA OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a transactional entity associated to another entity whereby the associated should not be updated in an case.

Eg. Case *-> User

Where a Case is owned by a User and reversely a User can have many associated Case.

The association is mapped using OneToMany and JoinColumn JPA annotations.

I have also tried marking the Trasactional annotation for User entity as readonly and also made the fetch methods Transient. But this doesnot seem to stop update on User if its state is changed.

Please help me a figure a way to declare a "read-only" association to User.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `updatable=false`on @JoinColumn annotation.

Furthermore you should not add a setter method for `user` in your `Case` entity and same for `caseSet` in your `User` entity. The getter `getCaseSet` in `User` entity should also return an unmodifiable collection:

```
public Set<Case> getCaseSet() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(caseSet);
}
```

Comment: Saved my day after struggling with this. Make sure you DO NOT add `nullable`.

Answer (score 4):

> The Column annotation and XML element defines insertable and updatable options. These allow for this column, or foreign key field to be omitted from the SQL INSERT or UPDATE statement. These can be used if constraints on the table prevent insert or update operations. They can also be used if multiple attributes map to the same database column, such as with a foreign key field through a ManyToOne and Id or Basic mapping. Setting both insertable and updatable to false, effectively mark the attribute as read-only.

In `@OneToMany` mapping, `@JoinColumn` annotation, add **both** `updatable=false` and `insertable=false`, then specify the cascade type as PERSIST instead of ALL 
`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

```
@JoinColumn(name = "<ReadOnlyTableName>", updatable = false, insertable = false)
```

Comment: insertable=false is throwing an error on insert, since the foreign key is not saved under the db. And using updatable false alone is not working (foreign table is updated).

Comment: question and answer is for read-only association